# Other than "childwife", is there a single word in English for "postpartum woman"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Other than "childwife", is there a single word for "postpartum woman"?

Comment: Where did you hear "childwife" used?

Comment: A childwife is a young mother. I believe a postpartum woman is just a mother, although it's not clear if the terminology is accurate in the case of loss.

Comment: @KillingTime I thought it sounded like Middle English, but the MED defines it as a midwife.